# /dev/video0 will not open, but the computer is aware a camera is connected. Ubuntu won't use the camera, but it works on windows

Tags: drivers, webcam

I dual boot ubuntu and windows on this laptop that has a built in web cam. The web cam works perfectly fine on windows, but doesn't work on ubuntu, and I don't know how to fix it. I looked at other questions that were similar to mine, but they didn't give a working solution. Here are some tests that I've seen several of them try, along with what I got putting them through the terminal

```
cd /dev/video0
bash: cd: /dev/video0: Not a directory
```

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:0306 Microsoft Corp. USB3.0 Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:09c0 Microsoft Corp. Surface Type Cover
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1286:204c Marvell Semiconductor, Inc. Bluetooth and Wireless LAN Composite
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : ipu3-imgu
    Card type        : ipu3-imgu
    Bus info         : PCI:0000:00:05.0
    Driver version   : 5.18.10
    Capabilities     : 0xa4202000
        Video Output Multiplanar
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x24202000
        Video Output Multiplanar
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
    Driver name      : ipu3-imgu
    Model            : ipu3-imgu
    Serial           : 
    Bus info         : PCI:0000:00:05.0
    Media version    : 5.18.10
    Hardware revision: 0x80862015 (2156273685)
    Driver version   : 5.18.10
Interface Info:
    ID               : 0x03000009
    Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
    ID               : 0x00000007 (7)
    Name             : ipu3-imgu 0 input
    Function         : V4L2 I/O
    Pad 0x01000008   : 0: Source
      Link 0x0200000b: to remote pad 0x1000002 of entity 'ipu3-imgu 0' (Video Statistics): Data
Priority: 2
Video output: 0 (ipu3-imgu 0 input)
Format Video Output Multiplanar:
    Width/Height      : 1920/1080
    Pixel Format      : 'ip3G' (10-bit bayer GRBG IPU3 Packed)
    Field             : None
    Number of planes  : 1
    Flags             : 
    Colorspace        : Raw
    Transfer Function : Default
    YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Default
    Quantization      : Default
    Plane 0           :
       Bytes per Line : 2496
       Size Image     : 2695680
```

It certainly detects something there, but none of the programs seem to be able to actually use it. So far, I've tested Firefox, Discord, Cheese, and guvcview. Discord and Firefox have just not been able to detect a camera and run just fine otherwise. On cheese, the screen is just black with the message "There was an error playing video from the webcam". When I go to change the device in preferences, I see "ipu3-imgu" 8 times. None of them work. When I open guvcview, a small error window immediately opens up saying, "no video device found. You seem to have video divices installed. Do you want to try one?" When I go to the drop down menu to select a divice, I see "ipu3-imgu" 10 times, and "Intel IPU3 CIO2" 4 times.

Currently on Ubuntu 22.04LTS, but for all I know, this could have been the case for a while

Edit: More tests:

```
sudo cheese
[sudo] password for user: 

(cheese:11404): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:37:57.992: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:11404): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:37:57.992: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:11404): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:37:57.992: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:11404): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:37:57.992: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:11404): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:37:58.050: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:11404): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:37:58.052: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:11404): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:37:58.054: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:11404): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:37:58.080: g_value_dup_string: assertion 'G_VALUE_HOLDS_STRING (value)' failed

(cheese:11404): cheese-WARNING **: 11:37:58.085: Device '/dev/video2' has no supported format: ../sys/v4l2/gstv4l2object.c(4038): gst_v4l2_object_set_format_full (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstWrapperCameraBinSrc:camera_source/GstBin:bin18/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src1:
Call to S_FMT failed for NV12 @ 4224x3136: Invalid argument
```

Cheese still doesn't work using sudo permissions. will open and run

```
ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  0 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  1 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 12 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video10
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 13 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video11
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 14 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video12
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 15 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video13
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  2 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  3 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video3
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  4 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video4
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  5 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video5
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  6 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video6
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  7 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video7
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  8 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video8
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  9 Jul 13 22:57 /dev/video9
```

Comment: try `ls -l /dev/video*`. Besides this, it might be the camera is not supported by Linux. "It works on Windows" just tells us, it is not broken.

Comment: Please run `sudo cheese` and see if the camera works to check whether it's a permissions issue.

Comment: @Marco, tried `ls -l /dev/video*` there are 13 dev/video files, numbered 0 to 13. @Raffa, tried running sudo cheese, same results as without the sudo. Thank you both

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
# change to your device name 
device="/dev/video0"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.