Camera not working after upgrading to 24.04
Having tried all the solutions on this site, none solve my problem. I have installed Cheese and camera is not found. The message is 'There was an error playing video from the webcam.' I installed snapshot and it freezes whenever I try to open it. If I restart the computer, I will receive a message that it cannot find the camera before freezing.

I have tried restarting pipewire and nothing changed, even after a restart.

I ensured that video group exists and that user is included. Groups listed: adm cdrom sudo audio dip video plugdev input lpadmin sambashare

When I run the code, 'v4l2-ctl --list-devices' what is returned is:
Integrated Camera: Integrated C (usb-0000:00:14.0-6):
/dev/video0
/dev/video1
/dev/media0

When I check, 'lsusb' one of the lines is, 'Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04f2:b6a8 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera'


Computer is a Lenovo with integrated webcam.
Any other suggestions would be appreciated.
Edit: webcam worked in previous version of Ubuntu.
Edit 2: dpkg -l cam | grep ii produces the following:
ii  gstreamer1.0-libcamera:amd64 0.2.0-3fakesync1build6 amd64        complex camera support library (GStreamer plugin)
ii  libcamd3:amd64               1:7.6.1+dfsg-1build1   amd64        symmetric approximate minimum degree library for sparse matrices
ii  libcamera0.2:amd64           0.2.0-3fakesync1build6 amd64        complex camera support library
ii  libwebcam0:amd64             0.2.5-4build1          amd64        Webcam Library
ii  webcamoid-data               9.1.1-1build6          all          icons and locale files for webcamoid
ii  webcamoid-plugins:amd64      9.1.1-1build6          amd64        full featured webcam capture application - plugins

when I open cheese from the terminal, this code follows:
[30:24:13.798393980] [126944]  WARN IPAManager ipa_manager.cpp:154 No IPA found in '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcamera'
[30:24:13.798471093] [126944]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:284 libcamera v0.2.0
** Message: 11:20:38.323: cheese-application.vala:222: Error during camera setup: No device found


(cheese:126944): cheese-CRITICAL **: 11:20:38.335: cheese_camera_device_get_name: assertion 'CHEESE_IS_CAMERA_DEVICE (device)' failed

(cheese:126944): GLib-CRITICAL **: 11:20:38.335: g_variant_new_string: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(cheese:126944): GLib-CRITICAL **: 11:20:38.335: g_variant_ref_sink: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:126944): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 11:20:38.335: g_settings_schema_key_type_check: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:126944): GLib-CRITICAL **: 11:20:38.335: g_variant_get_type_string: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(cheese:126944): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 11:20:38.335: g_settings_set_value: key 'camera' in 'org.gnome.Cheese' expects type 's', but a GVariant of type '(null)' was given

(cheese:126944): GLib-CRITICAL **: 11:20:38.335: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

** (cheese:126944): CRITICAL **: 11:20:38.335: cheese_preferences_dialog_setup_resolutions_for_device: assertion 'device != NULL' failed


sudo apt install uvcview then launch uvcview and see if the camera works in that application?

I think it's sudo apt install guvcview according to the available packages.

I could not find uvcview, but guvcview so I tried that. After install, I see a setting menu, but nothing seems to function. If I select the camera from the Device menu, I received an error message: no video device (/dev/video2) found. The pop-up goes on to state that I seem to have a video device installed and there is a drop-down list that shows my camera twice. If I select the first item, what I described above happens again. If I select the second, the error message reoccurs.

guvcview usually does it but try sudo apt install uvccapture libuvc0 uvcdynctrl

Also, check the permissions for /dev/video2 ls -la /dev/video*

https://askubuntu.com/a/1418724/167115

results of ls -la /dev/video* is
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Oct 23 07:31 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 2 Oct 23 07:31 /dev/video2.
I followed the linked solution and changed the video0 to the two that I have and in each case it reported back that the user already exists

Add your username to the video group and your cams will work again:
adduser your_username video
   adduser [--conf file] [--debug] [--quiet] [--verbose]
           [--stdoutmsglevel prio] [--stderrmsglevel prio]
           [--logmsglevel prio] user group

You'll need to log out, or (possibly) reboot, for this to show up in the groups command and become active.
NAME
       groups - print the groups a user is in

    SYNOPSIS
           groups [OPTION]... [USERNAME]...
    
    DESCRIPTION
           Print  group  memberships for each USERNAME or, if no USERNAME is speci‐
           fied, for the current process (which may differ if the  groups  database
           has changed).


user is already a member of the video group

@st.bobo Did you log out, or reboot, after using the adduser command?

yes. Still not working

@st.bobo If you start Cheese in the terminal, does it give any meaningful error messages?

@st.bobo Edit your question to add the output of 'dpkg -l *cam* | grep ii'

I added the requested information

@st.bobo When you upgraded to 24.04, did you do a "sudo apt-get autoremove"? Do you have 24.04 on a USB flash key... and if you boot to it, does the camera work then?

@st.bobo If solved? then please add the steps to follow, I am facing same issue, after upgrading to 24.04.1
